# Changing background color of a table cell using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

First of all I would like to explain what my task is. I had to create a 10X10 table using php filled with numbers from 1 to 100 and randomly select one table cell. Users task is to find that cell by clicking the table. After each click the distance between users click and the selected cell is being printed into text area. The code is working fine, but another thing I need to do is change the background color of a cell to red if the clicked cell wasn't the right one and to change it to green if the user guessed the cell. I have tried to implement call change into function, but it is called after the second guess and not already after the first. Can anyone help me please?

HTML/PHP CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>find cell</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
table{border-collapse:collapse;}
td{width:50px;height:50px;border: 2px solid #000000; background-color:#ff6600;color:white;text-align:center;}
h2{color:grey;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
function check(x,y){
    $.get("check.php?x="+x+"&y="+y, function(answer){
    $("#res").prepend(answer+"\n");
    });
}
</script>


</head>

<body>

<h1>Find cell...</h1>
<h2>(Refresh site to start again.)</h2>

<table>
<?php
session_start();

for($j=0;$j<10;$j++){
            echo "<tr>";
            for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
                    echo "<td onclick='check(".$j.",".$i.");'>".($j*10+($i+1))."</td>";
                }
            echo "</tr>";
        }

$_SESSION["rx"]=rand(0,9);
$_SESSION["ry"]=rand(0,9);
$_SESSION["p"] = 0;
?>
</table>

<br>

<form method="GET">
<textarea rows="30" cols="50" id="res" style="overflow:scroll;"></textarea>
</form>

</body>

<html>
```

check.php file:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["x"]) && isset($_GET["y"])){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["p"]++;
    if($_GET["x"] == $_SESSION["rx"] && $_GET["y"] == $_SESSION["ry"]){
        echo "Victorious after ".$_SESSION["p"]." tries.";
    }
    else{
        $distance = sqrt(($_SESSION["rx"]-$_GET["x"])*($_SESSION["rx"]-$_GET["x"])+($_SESSION["ry"]-$_GET["y"])*($_SESSION["ry"]-$_GET["y"]));
        echo intval($distance);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried to use CSS?

Comment: I have tried to change class of a cell depending on what function returned but no success so far.... Also tried changing css directly using jquery also no luck...

Comment: What have you tried thus far? We are here to help fix things that you have tried, not completely write a solution.

Comment: Post the jQuery script you tried. It is likely you are simply not targeting the correct DOM element to update the CSS.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the generated `table`? I'd like to try it on jsfiddle.

Comment: what do you mean, like a picture or something?

Comment: @Luki Nevermind, I made a 2x2 table because I couldn't wait for you anymore. Check my answer below.

Comment: @Luki By the way what does your `check.php` return?

Comment: I thought it returns the "answer", but I think I was wrong...

Comment: @Luki what I mean is what values does it give you. I'm looking for the actual value not the variable name.

Comment: @Luki Could you also show us the code for `check.php`?

Comment: I have included check.php file code above under the html code.

Comment: @Luki Oh yeah, sorry I didn't notice. But it looks like you got it now. Well done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you happen to want something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/uompg/r6xcn4kL/)?

#### HTML

```
<h1>Find cell...</h1>
<h2>(Refresh site to start again.)</h2>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-j="0" data-i="0">1</td>
      <td data-j="0" data-i="1">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-j="1" data-i="0">3</td>
      <td data-j="1" data-i="1">4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<form method="GET">
  <textarea rows="30" cols="50" id="res" style="overflow:scroll;"></textarea>
</form>
```

#### Script

```
var correctJ = 1; // Cell #3
var correctI = 0; // Cell #3

$("td").click(function() {
  if ($(this).attr('data-j') == correctJ && $(this).attr('data-i') == correctI) {
    $(this).css("background-color", "green");
  } else {
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
  }
});
```

Comment: That's exactly what I want to happen to my cells, but I have no idea how to implement that into my code...

Comment: @Luki It's basically the same thing. I just reduced the number of cells and hard-coded the correct cell coordinates because I couldn't use your `$.get()` link.

Comment: so should I add data-j and data-i attributes to my cells while generating table using php to check them that way?

Comment: @Luki As far as I know that's the general practice nowadays instead of putting `onclick` in your HTML. If you still want to do it the way you were doing it before feel free to do so. The main thing you should take a look at is the script.

Comment: @Luki give me a minute and I'll update my answer to reflect your coding style.

Comment: I finally managed to make this work, I understand now, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use an on-click event to add a css class with a different colour.

Comment: He knows that (he mentioned trying to do this in jQuery). Problem is he did not post the jQuery script he is trying to use in order for us to help debug it.

Comment: When you post an answer, try to elaborate it more adding a little chunk of code with and example, etc.